# Export view to animated GIF in NetLogo

Tags: view, export, gif, netlogo

Is there a way to export a NetLogo model's view into an animated GIF? I'm trying to create an animated GIF for a dynamic population density model and I'd like to embed the output as a moving GIF image on a webpage so the reader can see how the pattern is moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method is to use export-view on every tick using sequential file names
Put

```
   tick
   export-view (word ticks ".png")
```

in your "Go" procedure. Make sure your images are in their own directory. Use a gif making tool to convert the images to a gif. I use the gimp.